# Prove: $x^n=0 \to x=0$

Tags: proof-verification

I must prove the following:

**Prop.** : let $x \in \Bbb{R}, n \in \Bbb{N}-\{0\}$ then $$x^n=0 \to x=0$$
**Proof** : by contradiction I have $x \neq 0$, by [trichotomy](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Trichotomy_Law_for_Real_Numbers) one of the following holds

1. $x <0 $
2. $x >0$

1) if $x >0$ then $x^n>0$ therefore $x^n\geq 0$ and $ x^n\neq 0$ and (by hypothesis) $x^n=0$, this is absurd

2) if $x <0$ then:

- if $n$ is even then $x^n>0$ therefore $x^n\geq 0 $ and $ x^n\neq 0$ and (by hypothesis) $x^n=0$, this is absurd
- if $n$ is odd then $x^n<0$ therefore $x^n\leq 0 $ and $x^n\neq 0$ and (by hypothesis)
  $x^n=0$, this is absurd

Is this correct?

Comment: What is this wedge product?

Comment: @Semiclassical It's logical conjunction and disjunction: $\land$ is and $\lor$ is or. Your proof looks correct to me.

Comment: I believe he means "or" in logic. Though I think technically $x<0\oplus x>0$ should be in place of $x <0 \vee x >0$.

Comment: I figured out what OP means. This is a very unfortunately written post. What the first line should read is: Let $x^n = a$ and $a=0$, then $x=0$. This is really unnecessary and should instead be written let $x^n = 0$, then $x=0$. @mle, DO NOT mix "or" and "and" logical symbols with regular math. It is very confusing for the reader. Instead write out your statements in words. Overuse of symbols is bad form.

Comment: @CameronWilliams You're probably right. I'd attempted to edit some of the language to make it more understandable but some of it is quite confusing.

Comment: You should appeal to an axiom in each of the "therefore" statements you make, or otherwise use a different approach.

Comment: Please stop using $\wedge$ for "and" and $\vee$ for "or"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I'd take. More generally, I will use only the axioms of a field. I think the basic idea of your proof is good, but you don't justify why $x > 0$ implies $x^n > 0$. As I show below, you can avoid this casework altogether.

As you started, assume $x \neq 0$. We will show that this implies $x^n \neq 0$, which will give us the contradiction we want.

But to show this use contradiction within a contradiction argument. While $x \neq 0$, suppose $x^n = 0$ for some positive integer $n$. We must have $n > 1$ since $x^1 =x \neq 0$. Let $m > 0$ be the smallest such $n$. By the properties of a field, since $x \neq 0$, there is an inverse $x^{-1}$ so that $x^{-1}x^m = x^{-1}0 = 0$. But this means there is a smaller $n=m-1 > 0$ such that $x^n = 0$. This is a contradiction, so we must have $x^n \neq 0.$

But then as already mentioned, this is another contradiction. So the assumption $x \neq 0$ is false.

Comment: My one small edit to this is to change "for some $n$" to "for some positive integer $n$". Then you need to justify the definition of $m$ by noting that every nonempty set of positive integers has a least element by the well-ordering principle. This may beyond the OP's intended level of care, however.